# is there a hadith where muhammad, messenger of god, says like "accept hadith that you like"?

Tags: hadith

i read or heard a hadith where muhammad, salla llahu alayhi wa sallam, says like "if a hadith commands for good and you like it, then accept it, if it is for bad, then do not accept it".

seems a little book of hadithes i read had no references and (seems) there where many false hadithes. this might be in that book.

Comment: This is a bit too vague.

Comment: Never heard such..

Comment: i have found that there are several false hadith collections: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/6981/how-can-we-tell-the-saheeh-ahaadeeth-from-the-fabricated-ones : ... al-Ilal al-Mutanaahiyah by Ibn al-Jawzi, al-Manaar al-Muneef by Ibn al-Qayyim, al-Laaali al-Masnooah fil-Ahaadeeth al-Mawdooah by al-Suyooti, al-Fawaaid al-Majmooah by al-Shawkaani, al-Asraar al-Marfooah fil-Ahaadeeth al-Mawdooah by Ibn Arraaq, and Daeef al-Jaami al-Sagheer and Silsilat al-Ahaadeeth al-Daeefah wal-Mawdooah, both by Shaykh al-Albaani, ... maybe somebody can find this from there.

Comment: i have found something: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_hadith#Textual_Criticism : " [Sayings attributed to me] which agree with the Koran, go back to me, whether I actually said them or not ", " Whatever good sayings there are, I said them. "

Comment: https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/27 - like that